# AWS Lambda deploy list functions for local

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

`$ sls deploy list functions -s dev`

This will display a list of functions that are currently on the remote "dev" environment

**Question**

Is there a cli helper to see a list the functions that can be executed locally?

Currently I'm looking in my list of definitions (serverless.yml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sls info`.

Also, you can use `sls print` which is very similar to `cat serverless.yml`.